# chdir not working on Spartan 6 SP605 FPGA

Tags: fpga, xilinx, chdir, spartan

I am working on a project that uses the Spartan 6 FPGA eval kit.

The problem I am having is that when trying to change the directory on the CF card, the software can't build the working stack.

The directory is "a:\\setup" and that is being passed to the sysace_chdir(const char *path) function.
When I try to add some print code to debug the problem, none of the changes are registered.
In the SDK, I have the MicroblazeProc_hw_platform, then my project, then a standalone_bsp_0 project, which has the sysace_chdir() function in it.
When I build all the projects, the simple print statements (I use xil_printf() for output) do not display in the output.

Any help would be great.

PS - I am connected to the FPGA in the SDK using a COM port, and other print statements do get output during the initialization of the other things like the UARTs, so this is not a problem with output to the terminal or anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out what the problem was.

I inserted my card into a USB card reader and formatted it using a FAT32 file system.

As for the cnages in the BSP, I was not able to figure that out, but the code is now able to change directory.

The wierd thing is that after the code is executed, if I pull out the CF card and insert it into my pc, I don't see the newly created directory.  I don't know why.